# Define string literal in YAML

Tags: typescript, types, yaml

i try to define a string literal in YAML, but i dont get it to work. I want to define a type that looks in Typescript like this:

export type TypeName = "type1" | "type2" | "type3";

But i dont know how to define this in my yaml file. I hope you can help me.

Comment: Maybe it would help if you described the use case and what you mean by "type" in the context of YAML. How does the usual YAML _sequence_ `TypeName: ["type1", "type2", "type3"]` not suit your needs?

Comment: I want to have the type like writen above in a Typing file so i can type a variable with this type and only one of the values are allowed.
export type TypeName = "type1" | "type2" | "type3";
const Variable: TypeName = 'type1'; // OK
const Variable: TypeName = 'type7'; // NOT-OK

No i dont want an array with strings. I need the type like i wrote above. I need a string type with only the specified values.

Comment: What kind of YAML "Typing file" are you referring to? The deprecated [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) project used the typical-for-typescript combination of JSON and typescript files as far as I can tell. Typescript declaration files ("*.d.ts") are also written in typescript...